# In a Grid with value of Auto I cannot see the contents of the Label

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

In the `DataTemplat`e of a `CollectionView` I have a `Grid`, and inside it a `Row` to which I insert the `Height` value in `Auto`. I associate a `Label` with that `Row`, but it is not displayed, while if I insert an absolute value in the `Row` then the text is visible. How could I solve?

```
 <CollectionView
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=Constant,
                Constant=140}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                Type=RelativeToParent,
                Property=Width,
                Factor=1}"
                Margin="10,0">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" ItemSpacing="9"/>
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <yummy:PancakeView  CornerRadius="5">
                            <RelativeLayout>
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" RowSpacing="0.2">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="16"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <BoxView Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}"/>
                                    <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="8" Source="{Binding Umore}" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding GiornoTrascritto}" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.7" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Orario}" FontSize="14" TextColor="Black" Opacity="0.7" />
                                    <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DescrizioneUmore}" FontSize="16" TextColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"/>
                                    <FlexLayout 
                                        Grid.Row="4"
                                        Margin="0,5,10,0"
                                        Grid.Column="1"     
                                        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IconDiaries}" 
                                        Wrap="Wrap" 
                                        JustifyContent="Start" 
                                        Direction="Row" 
                                        AlignItems="Start" 
                                        AlignContent="Start">
                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Grid Padding="0,2,3,0">
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="17"/>
                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Black" Opacity="0.4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" CornerRadius="5" />
                                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding isSource}" Margin="3"/>
                                                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="{Binding ColoreUmore}" FontSize="12" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,3,0"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    </FlexLayout>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="7" BackgroundColor="Black" Opacity="0.2" Margin="0,0,4,4"/>
             THIS----->    <Label Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Nota}" Margin="5,0,9,0" />

                                    <Image Source="rightArrowB" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,10,0" Rotation="90" Opacity="0.4"/>
                                    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="21" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="BtOperazioni"/>
                                </Grid>
                                
                                <StackLayout
                                    RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=Constant,
                                    Constant=8}"
                                    RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
                                    Type=Constant,
                                    Constant=200}"
                                    HeightRequest="72"
                                    WidthRequest="90"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding Edit}">
                                    <Button Text="Modifica" BackgroundColor="Blue" Opacity="0.9" CornerRadius="5" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="37" />
                                    <Button Text="Elimina" BackgroundColor="Blue" Opacity="0.9" CornerRadius="5" TextColor="White" Clicked="EliminaDiario" HeightRequest="37" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </yummy:PancakeView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

Comment: Are you sure `Nota` is not empty ?

Comment: It has value. If I set the Row with a value, Example Height = "40", then I can read the content

Comment: @signalover I test your code, the Label text display correctly if I set grid height="Auto". If you still have this problem, please provide entire sample for me to test.

Comment: I have changed the code

Comment: @signalover I test your code, and using Frame replace yummy:PancakeView  , Nota display correctly, but FlexLayout don't display.

Comment: What is set as 'Auto' in the Row is not displayed. What can it depend on? In fact the FlexLayout in that case is in the Row with 'Auto' and is not displayed.